# Drawing continuously in drawing application

Tags: c++, drawing

I was wondering how drawing applications draw the entire time the mouse is down without having empty gaps. What I mean is, for example if the program only drew circles at the mouse's X, y coordinate, then if the mouse went too quicly it would seem like a bunch of little circles rather than a nice continuous line. How can this be done without constantly drawing a short straight line between where the mouse was 0.001 seconds ago and where the mouse now is. 
Thanks

Comment: @everyone: OP is asking how the *brush* tool works, not the *line* tool

Comment: @BlueRaja: what makes you think he/she/it is asking about the brush tool?

Comment: Yes it was the brush tool hence little circles :-p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It *can't* be done without constantly drawing a line between the current mouse point and the previous point, which is why this is what drawing programs generally *do* do.

Fancier drawing programs will fit curvy lines to multiple previous points to achieve a more natural drawing stroke, but the principle is the same.

**Update:**  Based on a comment, it appears that you have a timer involved in your drawing code.  This is surely unnecessary, since your application will generate a MouseMove event whenever the mouse is moved at all, and you can use that event to draw the next line.

Comment: Would it be a good idea to create arrays of these as instructions to generate lines, then push these into a queue for each operation then just pop them off for an undo?

Comment: @user146780: well, yeah, but you're basically describing what any modern graphics library does. I don't know what's available in the C++ world, but there must be a lot of choices to go with, as opposed to rolling your own.

Comment: Ok thanks! I'd rather do it on my own rather than use a lib because I want to learn and understand the underlying code.

Comment: @user146: If you are talking about undo/redo support, you'd want to undo the entire blob of drawing created using a single mouse click, not the individual lines drawn between frames

Answer (score 2):

You can draw a short *curved* line between where the mouse was 0.001 seconds ago and where the mouse now is.

The mouse positions are not continuous, if you move it faster than *very slowly*, you will get discrete unconnected points. You need to interpolate between these points using your preferred method.

Comment: Okay so the way I do it using a timer and drawing short straight lines is correct?

Comment: You could use a Bézier curve http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve to some good effect.

Comment: You don't need a timer.  You just need to record the previous mouse location, then draw a line to the current mouse location.  If you're doing fancier interpolation (say, cubic) you just need to keep track of more points in the past.

Comment: @user146780: Listen for the mouse move event if possible

Comment: @Nissan Fan: A better curve would be a cubic hermite spline like Catmull-Rom or a cardinal spline.  This way you can directly use the previously sampled points instead of offsetting them in order to get the tangents to line up.