# drawing a "preview" of line in simple graphical editor

Tags: c++, qt, drawing

Drawing line with QPainter.
onMousePressed : saving (x0,y0)
onMouseReleased : QPainter.drawLine (x0,y0,x1,y1)

I want to see preview of line onMouseMove. But if will redraw all picture it will be too long.
How to do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Drawing continuously in drawing application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2724651/drawing-continuously-in-drawing-application)

Comment: Sorry, bad close vote. Still slightly related though.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3040484/need-help-in-optimizing-a-drawing-code might be related too

Comment: "But if will redraw all picture it will be too long"... so you did actually try to do this? What is "too long", as in did you notice any serious lag?

Comment: "did actually try to do this" try with much calculating (big equation system) in draw event, but if i draw it to some buffer i think i can faster it. this is one way

Comment: What do you mean by the "much calculating" and "big equation system"? The question you have asked seems to indicate that you're trying to draw a simple line. Are you actually trying to plot (a system of) equations?

Comment: I think he means he has a complex model being rendered and on top of that he wants to be able to render a line that the user is currently dragging an endpoint for. This means redrawing the users line as the mouse moves and to do that, he has to redraw the underlying (and much more costly) model many times a second. I believe caching the rendering of the model in a buffer and then drawing the buffer and the frequently updating line is the answer as he already suspects.

Comment: @Arnold, Thanks for the clarification. :) Yeah, I would agree. That indeed that seems to be the most sane option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go simple for a first shot.

If your are not using any hardware accelerated rendering you can render in a `QPixmap` that you save as a member of your instance (lets call it `buffer`).

```
QPixmap* buffer = new QPixmap( this->size());
QPainter painter( buffer);
painter.draw(...) //draw your stuff in it
```

Then on paint when you track mouse moves render your `buffer` as a background (should be very fast since no transformation/blending is involved) then on top draw your dynamic line.

```
QPainter painter( this);
painter.drawPixmap( rect(), *buffer, rect());
painter.drawLine(...)
```

You must keep track of the dirtiness of your paint area to re-render `buffer` when needed (resize/stuff added/...).

NOTE: if your are using OpenGL same thing can be done with render buffer or pixel buffers ... see Qt PixelBuffer example

Answer (score 2):

Use a `QGraphicsScene`. Draw your background image as a `QGraphicsPixmapItem` and add the line preview as a `QGraphicsLineItem`. When the line is accepted, then remove the line item and draw it permanently on the pixmap. You can set the graphics scene to use OpenGL acceleration, http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qq/qq26-openglcanvas.html